# SQL's LIKE versus R's grep()

Tags: sql, r, string, sql-like

I have a SQL procedure I am attempting to recreate in R, but have reached a roadblock involving SQL's `LIKE` function.

In SQL there is a table with a column named Keys. I want to keep any of the rows such that
`"RR6GT|DS694100"` is `LIKE` the value of Keys in that row. When I try to recreate this in R using grep(), all the observations which were preserved in SQL are present, along with many other observations which were `NOT LIKE` in SQL. For example, in SQL the columns with the following values of Keys remain:

`"____[26ABEGJKPRT]%"`

`"____[2t]%"`

`"_____|_S%"`

When I replace "_" and "%"  with "?" and "*" respectively, these columns remain when using `grep()` in R. However `grep()` detects matches with:

`"????Z*"`

`"?R[67][S-W]*"`

`"[ELT1]*"`

I'm a bit lost, but suspect that `LIKE` and `grep()` may not behave the same way with respect to "%" and "*". I appreciate any insights of advice!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You are correct in your observation that `like` and `grep` are different.

Comment: In `grep` regex, with no `perl=TRUE`, you can match any single char with `.` (`_` in SQL wildcards), `%` can be matched with `.*` (any zero or more chars).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much! This eliminated many of R observations, but certain problematic ones such as `"[ELT1].*"` (opposed to SQL's `[ELT1]%` and `".....|.2.*"` (opposed to SQL's `"_____|_2%"`) still remain.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to subset the data based on the presence of a particular key - you are better off simply subsetting the data in R as opposed to using grep.

**SQL**

For instance, suppose there exists a table of place names in SQL.

We wish to select all place names beginning with "Am". This could be accomplished using LIKE as follows:

`select * from table where place like 'Am%';`

```
country    | place
-----------+-----------------------------------
Antarctica | Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station
Antarctica | Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station
Antarctica | Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station
```

Now, what if we wished to replicate this in R?

We can do so using `subset()`.

**R**

`subset(mydata, grepl("Am", mydata$place))`

```
X  country    place
1  Antarctica Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station
2  Antarctica Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station
3  Antarctica Amundsen-Scott South Pole Station
```

In this way, subset is scanning for a particular character that is present among the data in a column and returning the appropriate output.